# Unexpected behavior when inserting values into a map using a loop and a function

Tags: c++, loops, dictionary, memory

I'm quite the beginner at C++ but I was trying to write a Rainmeter plugin which basically does the following:

1. Scan all files in a directory set by Rainmeter options.
2. Filter out all directories that aren't `.` or `..` and only process those.
3. Add some data to a `map`, mostly calculated or fixed, with only the name directly influenced by the directory currently being processed.
4. Write the whole thing to an ini-formatted file (that's the reason for using `map`).

For debug reasons, I used the console instead of an actual filestream. And that's how I noticed the problem. For some mysterious reasons, probably references expiring because of objects going out of scope, the final output is totally messed up.
First of all, it only consists of one entry, no matter what method I use to iterate over it. Now it gets weird. In two places it uses the name of the last found directory and in two other places it uses the name of the first found directory. And this output doesn't change no matter what I try. I already tried putting the code from inside the loop into a separate function and back, using pointers and explicit memory allocation with `new` literally everywhere I could and intentionally not calling `delete` on those to try and keep them alive, and also using `shared_ptr` at some places.

This is the current code used at the relevant part

```
typedef std::pair<const TCHAR*, const TCHAR*> kv_pair;
int elem_index = 1;
std::map<const TCHAR*, std::map<const TCHAR*, const TCHAR*>> content;
WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
HANDLE hFind;
TCHAR[] measure_name = L"MeasureTest";
TCHAR[] dir = L"C:\\Foo\\Bar";
TCHAR[] searchPath = L"C:\\Foo\\Bar\\*"; //Of course these are actually dynamically sized

hFind = FindFirstFile(searchPath, &ffd);
//Error handling

do {
    if((ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) && (*ffd.cFileName != L'.')) {
        StringCchCat(dir, wcslen(dir) + wcslen(ffd.cFileName) + 2, L"\\");
        StringCchCat(dir, wcslen(dir) + wcslen(ffd.cFileName) + 2, ffd.cFileName);

        const TCHAR* name = ffd.cFileName;
        const TCHAR* measure_name = data->_measureName;

        std::map<const TCHAR*, const TCHAR*>* tmp = new std::map<const TCHAR*, const TCHAR*>;

        // BEGIN More or less irrelevant for the actual problem
        int col = ((int) elem_index / 5) + 1;
        int row = elem_index++ % 5;
        TCHAR* style = new TCHAR[wcslen(L"PlaylistGeneral | PlaylistRow1 | PlaylistCol1") + 1];
        StringCchPrintf(style, wcslen(L"PlaylistGeneral | PlaylistRow1 | PlaylistCol1") + 1, L"PlaylistGeneral | PlaylistRow%d | PlaylistCol%d", row, col);

        TCHAR* lmuAction = new TCHAR[wcslen(L"[!CommandMeasure  \"\"]") + wcslen(measure_name) + wcslen(path) + 1];
        TCHAR* rmuAction = new TCHAR[wcslen(L"[\"\"]") + wcslen(path) + 1];
        StringCchPrintf(lmuAction, wcslen(L"[!CommandMeasure  \"\"]") + wcslen(measure_name) + wcslen(path) + 1, L"[!CommandMeasure %s \"%s\"]", measure_name, path);
        StringCchPrintf(rmuAction, wcslen(L"[\"\"]") + wcslen(path) + 1, L"[\"%s\"]", path);
       // END More or less irrelevant for the problem


        tmp->insert(kv_pair(L"Meter", L"String"));
        tmp->insert(kv_pair(L"Group", L"Playlist"));
        tmp->insert(kv_pair(L"Hidden", L"1"));
        tmp->insert(kv_pair(L"Text", name));                    // These parts
        tmp->insert(kv_pair(L"MeterStyle", style));             // are the
        tmp->insert(kv_pair(L"LeftMouseUpAction", lmuAction));  // actual
        tmp->insert(kv_pair(L"RightMouseUpAction", rmuAction)); // problem

        content.insert(section(name, *tmp));
    }
} while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) && elem_index < 30);

//Some more error handling

for (const auto& section : content) {
    std::wcout << '[' << current.first << ']' << std::endl;

    for (const auto& kv : section.second) std::wcout << kv.first << '=' << kv.second << std::endl;
}
```

Running this with 3 folders being in `C:\Foo\Bar`, named `abc`, `def` and `ghi`, yields the following output

```
[ghi]
Meter=String
Group=Playlist
Hidden=1
Text=ghi
MeterStyle=PlaylistGeneral | PlaylistRow1 | PlaylistCol1
LeftMouseUpAction=[!CommandMeasure MeasureTest "C:\Foo\Bar\abc"]
RightMouseUpAction=["C:\Foo\Bar\abc"]
```

As visible, the key holding `name` uses the value from the last iteration of the `do-while` while `style`, `lmuAction` and `rmuAction` each refer to their first values and only the last entry actually shows up.

Finally, I've reached the point of running out of ideas so I came here.

Comment: Sorry for the typo in the title, wanted to change the first character and accidentally hit return together with backspace and the # character.

Comment: I strongly suggest you drop the manual memory allocation and use a `std::wstring` instead of all of the `TCHAR*`s.

Comment: @FallenWarrior There's an *edit* button.

Comment: @LogicStuff I knew, didn't know it could edit titles though. Maybe I'm a bit too accustomed to reddit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is `const TCHAR*` keys in your maps. As `std::map` compares key values to determine where to put data, it will not use the string `name` refers to;

Instead it will compare the pointer value itself - a memory address corresponding to `ffd.cFileName`, and that remains the same throughout the whole scope, which results in the single `std::map` entry.

Futhermore, `std::map::insert` does nothing when the key is already present in the map, which explains the fact that the data corresponds to the very first entry. As for the key itself, it always equals to `ffd.cFileName`, and as such the data it points to cycles through filenames and will stop at the last one.

The easiest (and correct) way to fix it is just as NathanOliver said - drop `TCHAR*`s altogether or at least in `std::map` etc, and use `std::wstring` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll try it out tomorrow. But now that you said it, it totally makes sense. I had that false assumption as I'm coming from C# where you can copy a string by simply assigning it to a new variable. Not wanting to try it but just for understanding: would this work if I copied `ffd.cFileName` to a `new TCHAR[]` using a copy function like `StringCchCopy` in each iteration?

Comment: @FallenWarrior Oh yeah, that should work, but then you'll have classical memory management problem on your hands - that new TCHAR[] will require a `delete` somewhere. Also naked `new`s are considered somewhat rude nowadays.

As you've said, `TCHAR*`, being a pointer, has no copying mechanics upon assignment, but `std::wstring` has - and this is exactly why it would work here. Worth noting that `std::wstring` also has a constructor that allows implicit cast from `TCHAR*` so just replacing `std::map` template arguments should do the trick. All other `TCHAR*`s can stay the way they are.

Comment: @Ap32 I'll probably still replace all that are possible for reasons of consistency. The only ones I gotta leave at their place are the `LPCWSTR`s the Rainmeter API uses. Still, using the implicit conversion to `std::wstring` will also do the trick for that, I think.